# Ajax json record count keep alert with 0

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vbscript, asp-classic

It's my first time try out ajax json. It's keep showing me the total record from server side is 0, although i hard coded in server side that Record : 1 still alert me record with 0. I'm wonder where did i did wrong. Is it the way from the array data that i pass is wrong? But none error message is showing out. Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "CL0022_CHECK_GL_INDICATOR.asp",       
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'arrGL':array.join('+++')},
        success: function (data) {


  alert(data.detail.Record)

            for(var i = 0; i < data.detail.Record; i++){

            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

> server side:

```
arrGL = Split(Request.Form("arrGL"),"+++")
arrLength = UBound(arrGL) + 1


Response.Write "{""detail"": {"
Response.Write """fields"": ["

For Each x In arrGL
    intcount = intcount + 1

    If intcount Mod 2 <> 0 Then 
        intcount2 = intcount2 + 1
        resetRst
        strSQL = " Select * from FLP003 Where ACCN='" & replace(x,"'","''") & "'"
        objRst.Open StrSQL,objConn
        If objRst.recordCount > 0 Then
            Response.Write "{""PSTIN"": """& trim(objRst.Fields("PSTIN"))&""","
            Response.Write """FSTAG"": """&trim(objRst.Fields("FSTAG"))&""","
            Response.Write """RECACI"": """&trim(objRst.Fields("RECACI"))&""","
        Else
            Response.Write "{""PSTIN"":"""","
            Response.Write """FSTAG"": """","
            Response.Write """RECACI"": """","
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write """LINE"": """& x &"""}"

        If arrLength <> intcount Then
            Response.Write ","
        End If
    End If
Next

Response.Write "],"
Response.Write """Record"": """& intcount2 &"""}}"
```

> I found the solution, just to change the method from GET to POST.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "CL0022_CHECK_GL_INDICATOR.asp",       
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { 'arrGL':array.join('+++')},
            success: function (data) {

   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to use `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` before alert. try it hope it will helps you. and also try thiss `alert(data.detail.Record.length);`

Comment: wow thanks @NiravJoshi its work when use this `alert(data.detail.Record.length);` Thanks! but it's shows me `data.detail.fields[i].PSTIN` is undefined, how to solve this?

Comment: that i have to check..

Comment: @Bills How's your json coming please show me.. put code. because i dont know about asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` before alert. try it hope it will helps you. and also try this `alert(data.detail.Record.length);`

**Update 2**

Try to use this

```
$.each(data.detail.fields,function(i){
    console.log(data.detail.fields[i].PSTIN);
});
```

> Try to do it with `jQuery.each()` it may helps you.

Comment: when i try to `alert($(data.detail.fields[i]).PSTIN)` it's show internal server error

Comment: i'm not using asp.net, it's asp classic

Comment: it's a jquery it will not show internal server error.. you get error in console. jquery is client side language not a serverside

Comment: owh yeah.. that's the wrong message i saw..it's actually show `undefined`

Comment: if i use datatype of text instead of json and i try to alert the data, it's actually show me this `{"detail": {"fields": [{"PSTIN": "","FSTAG": "G013","RECACI": "","LINE": "2"}],"Record": "1"}}`